# Switched to Angular4, material 2 autoComplete onSelect() not working

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

Just switched to Angular 4 and material 2 autoComplete's onSelect() on md-option is no longer working but I can't find any documentation on this. Whats the fix?

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayText.bind(this)">
<md-option (onSelect)="selectItem(item)" *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async" [value]="item">
  {{ item[propertyName] }}
</md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the answer it was changed to `onSelectionChange`.

Comment: Corect, but with starting lowercase: ´onSelectionChange´

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keyUp` event:

```
(keyup)="selectItem(item)"
```